# Excel::Shape object getting released automatically after the count reaches 18 in List<T>

Tags: excel, interop, clr, comexception

I have a Excel addin written in C# 2.0 in which I am experiencing a strange behavior.**Please note that this behavior is only seen in Excel 2003 and NOT in Excel 2007 or 2010.**

*Issue:*

When the user clicks an import command button, a file is read and a number of Shapes are created/added to the worksheet using Worksheet::Shapes::AddPicture() method. A reference to these Shape objects are kept in a generic list:

```
List<Excel.Shape> list = new List<Excel.Shape>();
```

Everything works fine till the list has less than 18 references. When the count reaches 18, and a new Shape reference is added, the first one i.e. @ index [0] is released. I am unable to call any method or property on that reference and calling a method/property throws a COMException (0x800A1A8) i.e. Object Required. If I add one more, then the reference @ [1] is not accessible and so on.

Strange enough... this happens with Shape object only i.e. If I add one Shape and then 17 nulls to the list then this wont happen until 17 more Shape objects are added.

**Does anyone has an idea why it happens after the count reaches 18?**

I thought it might be something with the List's default capacity. Something like relocating the references during which they get released so I initialized it with a capacity of 1000 but still no luck.

```
List<Excel.Shape> list = new List<Excel.Shape>(1000);
```

**Any Idea??**

---

**UPDATED**

Found that the exception generated while trying to access a Shape object through a string index is playing some role. When a new Shape is added, I check for an existing Shape object by calling Worksheet::Shapes::Item(shapename). This throws an exception if the Shape is not found. If I remove this line of code... it works fine.

Is there another way of checking if a Shape exists without generating this exception or iterating through the whole collection?

Answer (score 0):

There are many evil little bugs in Excel, unfortunately. Both in UI and VBA.

One of them is that when a user form created in Excel has more than {certain amount} of controls, referring to a control in the form of `Form.ControlName` will cause Excel to crash for no reason, but accessing the same control in the form of `Form.Controls("ControlName")` will work fine.

That's to say, try storing string names of the shapes instead, acquiring a new pointer each time you need it by querying `Worksheet::Shapes` collection with the name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried but still no luck. When I try to access the Shape from Shapes collection using the stored name, it throws an exception saying that the object does not exist.

Comment: Maybe it's the Shapes collection that does not exist then?
Can you iterate through the shapes manually, by clicking them?

Comment: Yes the Shapes collection exists because as I said, the Shapes are getting released after adding 18 objects. So I can access other Shape objects but not the previously added ones.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the Excel collection, not your list. I wonder what `Worksheet.Shapes.Count` gives, and what happens if you try to iterate through Worksheet.Shapes using an `int` indexer instead of the `string` one.